# How do I copy a struct

Tags: go

I want to copy an object so that I have two identical objects with two different memory addresses. My first attempt at this has failed:

```
aa := a
assert.NotEqual(t, &a, &aa, "Copied items should not be the same object.") // Test fails
```

Can I fix this so that it really does a copy of the struct? There's nothing special about this structure.

Comment: Please post more code to regenerate the issue you are facing. And you can use `reflect.DeepEqual` to check if two structs are equal.

Comment: If you're using testify, the docs say: `Pointer variable equality is determined based on the equality of the referenced values (as opposed to the memory addresses).` So this comparison probably isn't doing what you think it is in the first place.

Comment: If `a` and `aa` are both value types (not pointers), then you're already creating a copy. If they're not, dereference in the assignment to create a copy: `aa := *a`.

Comment: The addresses are different, but assert compares the values pointed to.

Comment: You may want the new [`assert.NotSame()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert#NotSame)

Answer (score 165, accepted):

In go, primitive types, and structs containing only primitive types, are copied by value, so you can copy them by simply assigning to a new variable (or returning from a function). For example:

```
type Person struct{
  Name string
  Age  int
}

alice1 := Person{"Alice", 30}
alice2 := alice1
fmt.Println(alice1 == alice2)   // => true, they have the same field values
fmt.Println(&alice1 == &alice2) // => false, they have different addresses

alice2.Age += 10
fmt.Println(alice1 == alice2)   // => false, now they have different field values
```

Note that, as mentioned by commenters, the confusion in your example is likely due to the semantics of the test library you are using.

If your struct happens to include arrays, slices, or pointers, then you'll need to perform a deep copy of the referenced objects unless you want to retain references between copies. Golang provides no builtin deep copy functionality so you'll have to implement your own or use one of the many freely available libraries that provide it.

Comment: seeing is believing https://play.golang.org/p/dZD8xoW_kvS

Comment: Arrays, specifically, are passed as values, though, as opposed to slices. Correct me if I'm wrong. https://go.dev/play/p/GzRAocbcBN5

Answer (score 10):

DeepCopy is a very heavy operation and hence should be avoided if possible. For complex structures such as the following, we can optimise the code.

```
type Address struct {
    city  string
    state string
}

type Person struct {
    age     int
    name    string
    address []Address
}

p := Person{
    age:  20,
    name: "Jack",
    address: []Address{
        {
            city:  "city1",
            state: "state1",
        }, {
            city:  "city2",
            state: "state2",
        },
    },
}

var q Person
q.age = p.age
q.name = p.name
q.address = append(q.address, p.address...)
q.address[0].city = "cityx"
```

Result:

```
p object:
{20 Jack [{city1 state1} {city2 state2}]}

q object:
{20 Jack [{cityx state1} {city2 state2}]}
```

Inference:
As can be seen from the above example, the p object did not change when q was changed. This approach can be used in nested array of structs.

Answer (score 7):

Be careful, if your source `struct` is actually a pointer, then a normal assign won't work:

```
package main
import "net/http"

func main() {
   a, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://stackoverflow.com", nil)
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   b := a.URL
   b.Host = "superuser.com"
   println(a.URL.Host == "superuser.com")
}
```

Instead, you need to dereference the pointer:

```
package main
import "net/http"

func main() {
   a, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://stackoverflow.com", nil)
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   b := *a.URL
   b.Host = "superuser.com"
   println(a.URL.Host == "stackoverflow.com")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try `gob.Encode` then `gob.Decode`, like we do in javascript: first `JSON.stringify` then `JSON.parse`.

In golang you should use `gob` instead of `json.Marshal/json.Unmarshal` because you don't need to add json tags on fields, and you can handle interface by using gob. Every interface used in you struct field should be called by `gob.Register`

```golang
import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/gob"
)

func DeepCopy(src, dist interface{}) (err error){
    buf := bytes.Buffer{}
    if err = gob.NewEncoder(&buf).Encode(src); err != nil {
        return
    }
    return gob.NewDecoder(&buf).Decode(dist)
}
```

`dist` should always be a pointer

Comment: It's easy to use, but about 100 times slower than recursively directly copying the fields/members.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a function with pass by value and return the argument untouched or changed depending on your needs.

Using the structs from above:

```golang
func main() {
    copyOf := func(y Person) Person {
        y.name = "Polonius"
        y.address = append(y.address, Address{
            city:  "other city",
            state: "other state",
        })
        return y
    }

    p := Person{
        age:  20,
        name: "Jack",
        address: []Address{
            {
                city:  "city1",
                state: "state1",
            }, {
                city:  "city2",
                state: "state2",
            },
        },
    }

    q := copyOf(p)

    fmt.Printf("Orig %v, \naddrss: %p \n\n", p, &p)
    fmt.Printf("Copy %v, \naddress: %p\n\n", q, &q)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing this is using a library (I'd recommend https://github.com/jinzhu/copier) combined with some reflection magic:

```
var cloneObj MyCustomStruct = reflect.New(reflect.ValueOf(sourceObj).Elem().Type()).Interface()
copier.Copy(cloneObj, sourceObj)
```

This gives you a deep copy of the source struct correctly typed (which is important). If you don't use an interface, you may need to customize the reflection use a bit (remove the `.Interface()`).