# Map elements not being properly copied in struct copy function

Tags: go, reference, copy, deep-copy

I have a function which copies a nary tree that looks like this:

```
func (e Expression) CopyTree() Expression {

    copy := NewEmptyExpression()

    copy.root = e.root

    for key, value := range e.auxMap {

        copy.auxMap[key] = value
    }
    for key, value := range e.treeMap {

        copy.treeMap[key] = value
    }
    for key, value := range e.parentMap {

        copy.parentMap[key] = value
    }
    for key, value := range e.childMap {

        copy.childMap[key] = value
    }
    copy.updateDisplay()

    return copy
}
```

The function `NewEmptyExpression()` just initialises those same maps to not be nil

I was under the impression that copying maps like this is deep copying, and that after calling this function I can now manipulate the copied tree without changing the original one, but this doesnt seem to be the case.

If i do this:

```
expanded := expression.CopyTree()

expanded.ReplaceNodeCascade(index, replacementExpression)
```

where `ReplaceNodeCascade()` looks like this:

```
func (e *Expression) ReplaceNodeCascade(index int, expression, test Expression) {

    parent := e.GetParent(index)

    if parent == -1 {

        e.SetExpressionAsRoot(expression)

    } else if parent >= 0 && len(e.treeMap) != 0 {

        otherRoot := expression.GetRoot()

        if (e.IsSummation(parent) && expression.IsSummation(otherRoot)) ||
            (e.IsMultiplication(parent) && expression.IsMultiplication(otherRoot)) {

            indexAsChild := e.GetIndexAsChild(index)

            e.RemoveNode(index, true)

            for _, otherChild := range expression.GetChildren(otherRoot) {

                e.InsertExpression(parent, indexAsChild, expression.CopySubtree(otherChild))

                indexAsChild++
            }

        } else {

            for len(e.GetChildren(index)) != 0 {

                e.RemoveNode(e.GetChildAtBreadth(index, 0), true)
            }
            e.treeMap[index] = *expression.GetNode(otherRoot)

            e.AppendBulkSubtreesFrom(index, expression.GetChildren(otherRoot), expression)
        }
    }
    e.updateDisplay()
}
```

`ReplaceNode()` looks like:

```
func (e *Expression) ReplaceNode(index int, symbol Symbol) {

    e.treeMap[index] = symbol

    e.updateDisplay()
}
```

`InsertExpression()` looks like:

```
func (e *Expression) InsertExpression(parent, index int, expression Expression) {

    children := e.GetChildren(parent)

    inserted := make([]int, 0)

    for i, child := range children {

        if i == index {

            insertedNode := e.AddToMap(*expression.GetNode(expression.GetRoot()))

            e.parentMap[insertedNode] = parent

            e.AppendBulkSubtreesFrom(insertedNode, expression.GetChildren(expression.GetRoot()), expression)

            inserted = append(inserted, insertedNode)

            inserted = append(inserted, child)

        } else {

            inserted = append(inserted, child)
        }
    }
    e.childMap[parent] = inserted

    e.updateDisplay()
}
```

then I end up with the original expression also being modified.

How can I fix this? I must have misunderstood deep copying, or maybe I have misunderstood pointer receivers

Comment: Im just worried the question will get very large, but will add them anyway

Comment: This looks like a shallow copy of those maps. Do those maps contain nested data which would be modified by this `ReplaceNode` function? I suspect if that's the case then you would see both expressions being modified.

Comment: @rchome this is the post which i have used as a reference to make my own function https://stackoverflow.com/a/23058707/14995113 supposedly this is a deep copy?

Comment: Oh i think i may have found a solution that has brought up another problem. The map called 'treeMap' consists of an int -> struct pair, and I was not properly copying that struct. But that brings up the question, how do I copy a struct?

Comment: maybe this could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/51638160/12005414